# How to share a variable between a MainActivity and a class that does not have onCreate

Tags: android

I need to share a variable "mconfigipaddress" that is in MainActivity with the class TcpClient, but this class does not have onCreate and when I try to do it using Intent it throws me an error, I also need to do it but without leaving MainActivity, someone can tell me how to do it?

Here is the code of the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private TcpClient mTcpClient;

public static String mconfigipaddress = "192.168.4.1";
public static String mconfigport = "8888";
.
.
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
.
.
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, TcpClient.class );
    intent.putExtra( "mconfigipaddressx", mconfigipaddress );
    intent.putExtra( "mconfigportx", mconfigport );
    startActivity( intent );
.
.
```

Here is the code of the TcpClient:

```
public class TcpClient {

private String  mconfigipaddress = ""; 
private String  mconfigport = ;
private String  mServerMessage;                        
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;    
private boolean mRun = false;                         
private PrintWriter mBufferOut;                       
private BufferedReader mBufferIn;                     
private String Modelox="";
public Boolean statusWIFIX = false;

/**
* Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages 
received from server
*/
public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
* Sends the message entered by client to the server
* @param message text entered by client
*/
public void sendMessage(String message) {
if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
    mBufferOut.println(message);
    mBufferOut.flush();
  }
}

interface TcpListener
{
void onReportStatusWIFIX(boolean statusWIFIX);
}

/**
* Close the connection and release the members
*/
public void stopClient() {

statusWIFIX = false;
sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION+": " + Modelox);                
mRun = false;
if (mBufferOut != null) {
    mBufferOut.flush();
    mBufferOut.close();
}
mMessageListener = null;
mBufferIn = null;
mBufferOut = null;
mServerMessage = null;
}

public void run() {
mRun = true;
try {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);      
    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);            
    try {
        //sends the message to the server
        mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new 
 OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        getDeviceName();
        mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        sendMessage(Constants.LOGIN_NAME+": "+ Modelox);                   

        statusWIFIX = true;

        while (mRun) {                                              
            mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
            if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);   
            }
        }
        Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + 
  mServerMessage + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
    } finally {
        socket.close();                                             

    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
  }
}

public interface OnMessageReceived {                                    
public void messageReceived(String message);                        
}
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: in TcpClient class, can you not access the variable via MainActivity.mconfigipaddress?

Comment: If it's static,why don't use MainActivity.mconfigipaddress... or is it going to be the same ip for the application and it won't change, why don't put it in the gradle or even the strings file?.

Comment: yes, now via MainActivity.mconfigipaddress I have the variable

Answer (score 1):

`TCPClient` is not an activity, hence is cannot be started with `startActivity(Intent intent)`. Try to build a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) for the `TCPClient` class.